# No matching unique or primary key for this column-list while query user_index table

Tags: oracle, indexing, unique, primary-key, rebuild

```
SELECT DISTINCT(UI.TABLE_NAME)
    ,UI_INDEX_NAME
FROM USER_INDEXES UI
INNER JOIN USER_TABLES UT ON UT_TABLE_NAME = UI.TABLE_NAME
INNER JOIN TMP ON TMP.TABLE_NAME = UI.TABLE_NAME
INNER JOIN USER_CONS_COLUMNS UC ON UC.TABLE_NAME = UI.TABLE_NAME
WHERE UT.IOT_TYPE IS NULL
    AND UC.COLUMN_NAME IN (
        'STAFF_ID'
        ,'STAFF_UNIQUE_ID'
        )
    AND UC.TABLE_NAME LIKE 'HR_%'
    OR UC.TABLE_NAME = 'PAYROLL';
```

Above table query the list of indexes referring to the table that having PK as `staff_id` or `staff_unique_id` from the table name `PAYROLL` and `HR_*`. `TMP` is the table that maintain these list of table name, as I don't want it to search through entire `USER_TABLE` or `USER_INDEX`.

I have no issue when manually select it, however error encountered:

> ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list

in PL/SQL while selecting the result and doing `INDEX REBULD`

The result return seem incorrect, many redundant `INDEX_NAME` that point to same table. I put a `DISTINCT` for `UI.TABLE_NAME` to solve the duplicate. But in PLSQL, i do not need to populate `UI.TABLE_NAME`, so how can the error come from?

```
--index rebuild
FOR r IN (....) LOOP
   l_sql := 'ALTER INDEX '||r.index_name||' REBUILD';   
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_sql; 
END LOOP;

--disable constraint
FOR m IN (SELECT UC.CONSTRAINT_NAME ,UC.TABLE_NAME FROM USER_CONSTRAINTS UC
          INNER JOIN TMP ON UC.TABLE_NAME = TMP.TABLE_NAME
          WHERE UC.TABLE_NAME = TMP.TABLE_NAME AND UC.CONSTRAINT_TYPE IN 
          ('R', 'C', 'U') AND UC.TABLE_NAME LIKE 'HR_%' OR UC.TABLE_NAME = 
          'PAYROLL') LOOP
     l_sql := 'ALTER TABLE '||m.TABLE_NAME||' DISABLE CONSTRAINT 
              '||m.CONSTRAINT_NAME||' CASCADE';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_sql; 
END LOOP;

--enable constraint
 FOR n IN (SELECT UC.CONSTRAINT_NAME ,UC.TABLE_NAME FROM USER_CONSTRAINTS UC
          INNER JOIN TMP ON UC.TABLE_NAME = TMP.TABLE_NAME
          WHERE UC.TABLE_NAME = TMP.TABLE_NAME AND UC.CONSTRAINT_TYPE IN 
          ('R', 'C', 'U') AND UC.TABLE_NAME LIKE 'HR_%' OR UC.TABLE_NAME = 
          'PAYROLL') LOOP
    l_sql := 'ALTER TABLE '||n.TABLE_NAME||' ENABLE CONSTRAINT 
             '||n.CONSTRAINT_NAME||'';
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_sql; 
   END LOOP;
```

Comment: You need to show us the PL/SQL code that throws the error. Also `distinct` is *not* a function, it applies to the whole row not a single column; and you refer to PKs but you aren't restricting to just those constraints. And you might want parentheses to clarify/control the precedence of AND and OR in your filter.

Comment: are your column names really lower case?  that could cause an issue, it might not be finding rows or it might be causing your index rebuild to fail, you might want to make that upper case? just a guess. 
 respectfully, distinct can be used like a function, it is confusing to me so i don't do it but the syntax is valid

Comment: @ Peter M, yes, column name is uppper case, but it doesn't sound matter

Comment: @ Alex Poole, i added the PL/SQL code for index rebuilding, there has no `distinct` in the SQL of the `FOR..LOOP`. I have another 2 loops to disable and enable constraint using the similiar logic to restrict the table name.